# Every second element from list

Tags: haskell

I am trying to print every second element from list of lists

```
fun [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]] = [2,5,7]
```

I have this:

```
fun xs = fmap head xs
```

but this returns every first elem from lists

Comment: ``fun xs = fmap (head.tail) xs``

Comment: and you know how to take every seond element from pairs in list and square it? [(1,2),(3,4),(3,2)] = [4,16,4] using recursion

Comment: Will the answer really help you?

Comment: ``fun2 :: [(Int,Int)] -> [Int];fun2 [] = [];fun2 ((a,b):ts) = (b^2):fun2 ts``

Comment: @DavidLukas Answer questions in Answers, please, not comments.

Comment: What if the sublists do not have two (or more) items?

Comment: Don't you want to learn to do it  yourself first,  with recursion only?  If not, are you familiar with list comprehensions?

Comment: `head` returns the first element of the list. So just replace it with a function that returns the *second* element of the list. Don't worry about lists of lists; `fmap` already takes care of that. Focus on writing `second :: [a] -> a`.

Answer (score 1):

I Just changed the output to `[Maybe a]` because using just `fmap` or `map` with head.tail cant handle the exception of shorter lists.
Also I generalized to N'th index:

```haskell
takeNthIndex :: (Eq t, Num t) => t -> [a] -> Maybe a
takeNthIndex _ [] = Nothing
takeNthIndex 0 (x:xs) = Just x
takeNthIndex n (x:xs) = takeNthIndex (n-1) xs

everyNthIndex :: (Eq t, Num t) => t -> [[a]] -> [Maybe a]
everyNthIndex _ [] = []
everyNthIndex n (x:xs) = takeNthIndex n x : everyNthIndex n xs

everyNthIndexByMap :: (Eq t, Num t) => t -> [[a]] -> [Maybe a]
everyNthIndexByMap n = map (takeNthIndex n)
```

Usage:

```haskell
everyNthIndex 1 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8], []]
-- output: [Just 2,Just 5,Just 7,Nothing]
```

`everyNthIndex` is the recursive version of `everyNthIndexByMap`